# No correct resolution after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hdmi, vga, display-resolution

I recently installed the relevant nvidia drivers via the edgers ppa, and it definitely worked because my frame rate in minecraft went from 10 to over 200. But the problem now is that the resolution is screwed up. As far as I can tell, the correct resolution should be 1024x768 but nvidia thinks it should be 1280x720. Either way, both resolutions look terrible now, as do the rest of the options.

1024x768 looks the best, but the aspect ratio is 4:3 I think, when it should be 16:10 or 16:9. I have no idea how to fix this..

I'm using ubuntu 14.04, my graphics card is a geforce GTX 750 Ti.

This isn't as important, but also after installing the driver, it takes at least a minute or two for my computer to recognize my wireless mouse and keyboard.

EDIT - I've plugged in my VGA cable and managed to get a tolerable resolution with it in the meantime. Of course I would much rather use the HDMI. I've tried so many things including changing xorg's configuration with nvidia-xconfig, having no xorg, changing the resolution in nvidia-settings, xrandr, etc. I've tried switching from the different nvidia driver versions (340, 346, 352). I even switched back temporarily to the nouveau driver and now that resolution is cut off on the bottom.

EDIT2 - I've gotten the resolution perfect now for VGA, although I'm not entirely sure how I did it. I kept tinkering around with the resolution and eventually tried unplugging the HDMI cable so only the VGA was plugged in and then restarted. This is still not ideal obviously since I would much rather be using HDMI, but I may have to stick with VGA for now because I have no idea how to fix it for HDMI...